# How do I use Data::Section?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I just found [Data::Section](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aSection) and I got interested in it. Unfortunately, I simply cannot get the `package Letter::Resignation` example on that page to run.

Are there any working examples of Data::Section out there?

Comment: Related: [Inline::Files](http://p3rl.org/Inline::Files), [Data::Section::Simple](http://p3rl.org/Data::Section::Simple)

Comment: Just a note: `Data::Section` has to have first backslash on line in included files (from `__DATA__` section) escaped; `Data::Section` and `Data::Section::Simple` allow period in "filename", however, the list of "included files" is returned as a hash, and not in order of appearance; `Inline::Files` doesn't run with `use strict`, has a different concept so "filenames" are used to define file handles, thus they cannot contain period/dot - and there is no complete file list (in a hash or otherwise) that I can see there (unless all "filenames" start with the same word).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after some not-so-trivial searching on the net, I finally managed to find the one (and only, I guess) example on the net that I could read here:

- [RJBS Advent Calendar 2009 - Like <DATA>, Only Less Stupid](http://advent.rjbs.manxome.org/2009/2009-12-09.html)

That finally explained to me how to set up the Data::Section - the trick is it always needs a package name reference. And finally, for expanding variables in the section, [How can I expand variables in text strings? - perlmonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20can%20I%20expand%20variables%20in%20text%20strings%3F) was very useful.

So here is an MWE if you do not want to use a package name:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use charnames ':full';

# sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
# install Data::Section

use Data::Section -setup; 

my $name = "testing \t escapes \n variable";

my $sections = main::->merged_section_data;
for my $filename (keys %$sections) {
  printf "== %s ==\n%s\n", $filename, main::->section_data($filename);
}
my $template = main::->section_data ("test_file");

# expands variables in the template as well!!
$$template =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg;
die if $@;                  # needed on /ee, not /e

print $$template;



__DATA__

__[ test_file ]__
  \t testing \r escapes \n data::section \t

    Here

  --
  {{ $name }}



__END__
```

If you use a package name, just a slight difference:

```
package aPerlTest;

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use charnames ':full';

# sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
# install Data::Section

use Data::Section -setup; 

my $name = "testing \t escapes \n variable";

my $sections = aPerlTest::->merged_section_data;
for my $filename (keys %$sections) {
  printf "== %s ==\n%s\n", $filename, aPerlTest::->section_data($filename);
}
my $template = aPerlTest::->section_data ("test_file");

# expands variables in the template as well!!
$$template =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg;
die if $@;                  # needed on /ee, not /e

print $$template;



__DATA__

__[ test_file ]__
  \t testing \r escapes \n data::section \t

    Here

  --
  {{ $name }}



__END__
```

In both case, the terminal output is:

```
$ perl aPerlTest.pl
== test_file ==
SCALAR(0x9f079d0)
  \t testing \r escapes \n data::section \t

    Here

  --
  {{ testing     escapes 
 variable }}
```

Hope this helps someone - cheers!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this a while ago: you can also see an example at http://pukku.com/bostonpm/2014-01-xslt/bostonpm.html